# zf2 Form Bind Object Issue

Tags: forms, binding, zend-framework2

I have a problem with zf2, form bind object procedures, to put it short I am trying to automate data exchange to my entity from form object once form validation is through, for which I had implemented two interfaces **InputFilterAwareInterface** and **ArraySerializableInterface**, the earlier interface is for form object to get the input filters and the later interface is for data exchange from forms and my entity. below is a short snippet of the code put in my controller.

```
//Controller code
$companyForm = new \Manage\Forms\CompanyForm();
$companyEntity = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Manage/CompanyEntity');
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray();
$companyEntity->exchangeArray($postData);
$companyForm->bind($companyEntity);
if($companyForm->isValid(){
    ....
}
```

this should automatically **call exchangeArray()** method in my entity object and it **does so correctly** but the **issue** is the **data are empty** and also the data array contain keys that has inputfilter set all other data keys are missing.

I can add more code snippets if need.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binding an entity to a form is usually done with a hydrator. A hydrator converts an array of data to a value object and vice versa. Therefore, you need to configure your form to have the correct hydrator suited for your entity.

If you have, for example, various properties (say, `bar` and `baz`) for your entity `Foo` and configure `getBar()`, `setBar()`, `getBaz()` and `setBaz()` methods, you can use the `ClassMethods` hydrator:

```
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\StdLib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;

class Foo extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethods);

       // More here for the elements now
    }
}
```

And your entity:

```
class Foo
{
    public function getBar() {...}
    public function setBar() {...}

    public function getBaz() {...}
    public function setBaz() {...}
}
```

Then your controller looks like this:

```
public function createAction()
{
    $entity = new My\Entity\Foo;
    $form   = new My\Form\Foo;
    $form->bind($entity);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequiest()->getPost();
        $form->setData($data);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // $entity is now populated with data
            // persist $entity here
        }
    }

    // create view model here
}
```

This will work if you have elements "bar" and "baz" in your form and provided the correct input filter to grab the "bar" and "baz" form data and filter them.

Comment: I had checked the Zend/Form code and it uses a default hydrator ArraySerializable, which is sufficient for my use.

From your answer, I am now clear filter is what that prevents the other data keys, but still not clear why the data are empty?

Iam sure data is inside the form else isvalid() would return false. any idea how to get the data back from the forms?, I am looking for the data from the form is to get normalized data

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the Zend/Form code, iif object is not bounded it uses the existing filters created by isvalid() method. if binding object is there the inputfilter is recreated but not initialized with data that is why I got empty data. adding a line of code solved the issue. I am going to report this issue to zf2 bugs, I am accepting your answer and closing the question, thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

`ClassMethods` hydrator (during extraction) converts results from getters such as "getSomeProperty" to an array value for the key "some_property"

If your form element name is "someProperty" extraction and hydration will not occurr.

Basically:

"getProperty"     getter <=> "property"      key (NO problem here)

"getSomeProperty" getter <=> "some_property" key

In order to extract and hydrate form elements with camel-cased names corresponding to camel-cased object properties do this:

`$myform->setHydrator(new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods(false));`

the "false" parameter instructs the hydrator NOT to convert camelCase to lowercase_underscore

you can do that in your form constructor.